# Changing the title of a page that has been set in a different file

Tags: php, html

I am currently working on updating the title of a few pages that I created a while ago. I currently set the title for all of the pages inside a header.php file which I then include from all of my other pages to update the titles.

However, now I want to update the title of the other pages to include the current title in Addition to particular tab they are in. Each tab is a different file. Tab_A.php, Tab_B.php, etc.
Is there a way to do that by just updating my header.php file?

This is the content of the header.php file

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Website</title>
</head>
<body>
```

I set the title in Tab_A.php by calling this inside it like this

`<?php include("header.php"); ?>`

But I would like the title to be change to read "Tab_A - My Website"

Comment: What is going wrong, can you please include?

Comment: This isn't a difficult problem, but without seeing what you're doing right now it's difficult to suggest a solution. Post some code.

Comment: My Tab_A page will only display the "My Website" title and not the "Tab_A - " part since the setting of the title is handled by the header.php file which is only included in the Tab_A.php file. I just would like to update header.php to change the titles for the other pages.

Comment: Let me add some code

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually doing anything dynamic.

Assume the following

header.php

```
$page_title='My Fun Page Title'
```

for your output file, it'll need to *also* be a PHP file, not a HTML file and the title tag would be

```
<title><?php echo $page_title;?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

Tab_A.php

```
$title = "Tab_A";
```

Tab_B.php

```
$title = "Tab_B";
```

header.php

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $title." - My Website"; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
```